# Scraping Trustpilot and storing results in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to extract all the reviews for the first 20 pages from Trustpilot

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Initialize lists
review_titles = []
review_dates_original = []
review_dates = []
review_ratings = []
review_texts = []
page_number = []

# Set Trustpilot page numbers to scrape here
from_page = 1
to_page = 20

for i in range(from_page, to_page + 1):
   response = requests.get(f"https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.abc.com?page={i}")
web_page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")

for review in soup.find_all(class_ = "paper_paper__1PY90 paper_square__lJX8a card_card__lQWDv card_noPadding__D8PcU card_square___tXn9 styles_navigationContainer__kPGA_"):
    # Review titles                  
    review_title = review.find(class_ = "typography_heading-s__f7029 typography_appearance-default__AAY17")
    review_titles.append(review_title.getText()) 
    # Review dates
    review_date_original = review.select_one(selector="time")
    review_dates_original.append(review_date_original.getText())

    # Convert review date texts into Python datetime objects
    review_date = review.select_one(selector="time").getText().replace("Updated ", "")
    if "hours ago" in review_date.lower() or "hour ago" in review_date.lower():
        review_date = dt.datetime.now().date()
    elif "a day ago" in review_date.lower():
        review_date = dt.datetime.now().date() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
    elif "days ago" in review_date.lower():
        review_date = dt.datetime.now().date() - dt.timedelta(days=int(review_date[0]))
    else:
        review_date = dt.datetime.strptime(review_date, "%b %d, %Y").date()
    review_dates.append(review_date)

    # Review ratings
    review_rating = review.find(class_ = "star-rating_starRating__4rrcf star-rating_medium__iN6Ty").findChild()
    review_ratings.append(review_rating["alt"])
    
    # When there is no review text, append "" instead of skipping so that data remains in sequence with other review data e.g. review_title
    review_text = review.find(class_ = "typography_body-l__KUYFJ typography_appearance-default__AAY17 typography_color-black__5LYEn")
    if review_text == None:
        review_texts.append("")
    else:
        review_texts.append(review_text.getText())
    
    # Trustpilot page number
    page_number.append(i)

 # Create final dataframe from lists
df_reviews = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(review_titles, review_dates_original, review_dates, 
review_ratings, review_texts, page_number)),
            columns =['review_title', 'review_date_original', 'review_date', 
'review_rating', 'review_text', 'page_number'])
```

and I am getting the following error

```
  AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
   24         # Review titles
   25         review_title = review.find(class_ = "typography_heading-s__f7029 
   typography_appearance-default__AAY17")
 ---> 26         review_titles.append(review_title.getText())
    27         # Review dates
  28         review_date_original = review.select_one(selector="time")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

I understand that one of the review titles are coming out to be None and the same issue is persisting for other elements as well such as Dates, Pages, Review etc.

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this exact exercis 3 months ago, the code that worked for me was the following:

```
from time import sleep
import requests

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def soup2list(src, list_, attr=None):
    if attr:
        for val in src:
            list_.append(val[attr])
    else:
        for val in src:
            list_.append(val.get_text())

users = []
userReviewNum = []
ratings = []
locations = []
dates = []
reviews = []

from_page = 1
to_page = 60
company = 'eshakti.com'

for i in range(from_page, to_page+1):

   result = requests.get(fr"https://www.trustpilot.com/review/{company}?page={i}")
   soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content)

   # Trust Pilot was setup in a way that's not friendly to scraping, so this hacky method will do.
   soup2list(soup.find_all('span', {'class','typography_heading-xxs__QKBS8 typography_appearance-default__AAY17'}), users)
   soup2list(soup.find_all('div', {'class','typography_body-m__xgxZ_ typography_appearance-subtle__8_H2l styles_detailsIcon__Fo_ua'}), locations)
   soup2list(soup.find_all('span', {'class','typography_body-m__xgxZ_ typography_appearance-subtle__8_H2l'}), userReviewNum)
   soup2list(soup.find_all('div', {'class','styles_reviewHeader__iU9Px'}), dates)
   soup2list(soup.find_all('div', {'class','styles_reviewHeader__iU9Px'}), ratings, attr='data-service-review-rating')
   soup2list(soup.find_all('div', {'class','styles_reviewContent__0Q2Tg'}), reviews)

   # To avoid throttling
   sleep(1)

review_data = pd.DataFrame(
{
   'Username':users,
   'Total reviews':userReviewNum,
   'location':locations,
   'date':dates,
   'content':reviews,
   'Rating': ratings
})
```

The likely reason is that the HTML header names changed overtime. Note that you'll need to change the `i` range in the for loop to match the pages and change the company name.

Comment: You are a star! Thank you! and your version is so simplified as well.

Comment: how do I add the review title as well? I am trying to do this soup2list(soup.find_all('div', {'class','typography_heading-s__f7029 typography_appearance-default__AAY17'}), reviews_title) and then add the reviews title back into the dataframe but it says that all arrays must be of same length

Comment: I changed `'div'` to `'h2'` and it worked. With `'div'` I was getting an empty list, since the tag is `h2` not `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Before apply a method to an object it would be always a good idea to check if this exists to avoid the shown error:

```
e.select_one('[data-service-review-text-typography]').text if e.select_one('[data-service-review-text-typography]') else None
```

I would also recommend **avoid these `list`s unless you can guarantee that they are all the same length**, instead use a single one with a structured `dict`.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


data = []
# Set Trustpilot page numbers to scrape here
from_page = 1
to_page = 20

for i in range(from_page, to_page + 1):
    response = requests.get(f"https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/www.asda.com?page={i}")
    web_page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")

    for e in soup.select('article'):
        data.append({
            'review_title':e.h2.text,
            'review_date_original': e.select_one('[data-service-review-date-of-experience-typography]').text.split(': ')[-1],
            'review_rating':e.select_one('[data-service-review-rating] img').get('alt'),
            'review_text': e.select_one('[data-service-review-text-typography]').text if e.select_one('[data-service-review-text-typography]') else None,
            'page_number':i
        })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Your solution has also worked pretty well and I do understand your point, Thanks much for taking the time and providing me with an input.. :)